# How to restrict the some iOS Push Notification message to user while app is background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working on iOS application, it contains one task about to restrict the some Push notification to user when our app is in background.

consider this example if user have 4 types push notification of our
    project like:

1. Some one sent Friend request.
2. Some one like his comment.
3. Some one share his comment.
4. Some one send message to user.

if user did want to push notification for Type 1 and 4 without using of server side script while our app is in background?.

**Note:** how to handle the push notification message of our application before it add in notification centre?

Comment: once the notification is fired then you cant stop it, you can set some cron job to handle those in a custom way.

Comment: You should send a silent push and the post a local notification if required based on the push data and the application state